# Sum a cols by range from an other colum

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is my problem :

In my dataframe i have two cols : km and value

```
    km    value
0   1      10
1   10     2
2   3      5
```

and i would like to make sum of value from range of km
like a sum of value for 1 < km =< 3 then 3 < km =< 6 etc ...

i've tried this :

```
 i = 0
 j = 3
 while j < 200 :
     sum_km = dvf[i < dvf['km'] and j >= dvf['km'] ]['value'].sum()
     i += 3
     j += 3
```

but i have :

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I would like to have at the end :

```
Total value for 1 at 3 kms : 15
Total value for 3 at 6 kms : 0
Total value for 6 at 9 kms : 0
Total value for 9 at 12 kms : 2
```

Comment: How are you defining the range for the km?

Comment: @dper done editing

Comment: can you post a desired output? Are you trying to performing a windowing operation?

Comment: You have a logic issue here , 1-3 you considered 3 in it and 1 in it too, but 3-6 you did not consider 3 in it

Answer (score 2):

If you want all intervals:

```
width = 3
min_val = dvf['km'].min() - 1
max_val = dvf['km'].max()
bins = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples([(x, x+width) for x in range(min_val, max_val, width)])
dvf.groupby(pd.cut(dvf['km'], bins = bins))['value'].agg('sum')



>>> output

km
(0, 3]     15
(3, 6]      0
(6, 9]      0
(9, 12]     2
```

I'll leave the pint formatting to you as that seems to be besides the main problem.

Comment: You can build your bins more succinctly using `bins = pd.interval_range(df['km'].min()-1, df['km'].max(), freq=3)`

Answer (score 1):

My solution is similar to ansev's except I interpreted your grouping a little differently.

```
df['bin'] = (df['km']/3).astype(int)
df[['bin','value']].groupby('bin').agg(sum)
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution `pd.cut`

```
df.value.groupby(pd.cut(df.km,[0,3,6,9,12])).sum()
Out[400]: 
km
(0, 3]     15
(3, 6]      0
(6, 9]      0
(9, 12]     2
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [`pd.interval_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.interval_range.html) + [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

```
bins=pd.interval_range(df['km'].min()-1, 12, freq=3)
df.groupby(pd.cut(df['km'],bins)).value.sum()
```

---

```
km
(0, 3]     15
(3, 6]      0
(6, 9]      0
(9, 12]     2
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score -2):

You need boolean operators:

```
dvf[(i < dvf['km']) & (j >= dvf['km'])]['value'].sum()
```